# What is purpose of using mysql_secure_installation?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to install MySQL on Ubuntu 12.04.

I want to use this command `sudo mysql_secure_installation` in Terminal, but I don't know the purpose of this command.

Comment: To secure your MySQL installation...

Comment: Read the man page here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-secure-installation.html

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's designed to set a few initial parameters that are more secure than the default Ubuntu (and MySQL) installation.

According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-secure-installation.html:

> This program enables you to improve the security of your MySQL installation in the following ways:
>
> - You can set a password for root accounts.
> - You can remove root accounts that are accessible from outside the local host.
> - You can remove anonymous-user accounts.
> - You can remove the test database (which by default can be accessed by all users, even anonymous users), and privileges that permit anyone to access databases with names that start with test_.