# Why use 'mysql_secure_installation' with MySQL5.7?

Tags: mysql

[`mysql_secure_installation`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-secure-installation.html) is basically just [a couple of SQL commands](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysql_secure_installation/) to make MySQL more secure.

I installed mysql-server 5.7 on Ubuntu 18.04 and ran the commands manually, as described [here](http://bertvv.github.io/notes-to-self/2015/11/16/automating-mysql_secure_installation/):

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string='secretpassword' WHERE user='root';
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user='';
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user='root' AND Host NOT IN ('localhost', 
'127.0.0.1', '::1');
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test;
DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE Db='test' OR Db='test\\_%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Apart from changing the root password, each of the commands showed no effect at all:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

I have two questions:

1. Why would I want to use `mysql_secure_installation` if it does not
   have any effect?
2. Why would I want to set a root password if I stick
   with the default `auth_socket` authentification?

Note: As I am interested in the technical details, this is *not* a 'possible duplicate' of [What is Purpose of using mysql_secure_installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760908/what-is-purpose-of-using-mysql-secure-installation) ;-).

Answer (score 1):

Using `mysql_secure_installation` is not a must. No need to use it if you don't need it. As the document said in your link provided in your question, it is just for helping you implement security recommendation (ie, remote root access, etc) :

> mysql_secure_installation helps you implement security recommendations
>   similar to those described at Section 2.10.4, “Securing the Initial
>   MySQL Accounts”.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-secure-installation.html

The default initiali here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/default-privileges.html

If you are 100% sure will not get any remote attack or access from your local with default root access and any problem described there, actually you can ignore it.

Since this mysql is open source, actually you can know any technical details about any mysql problem with knowledge needed here https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server

Comment: Thank you, @jun-rikson! To specify: my question is not whether I want to opt for more or less security. I would like to find out, if running mysql_secure_installation is redundant or not (given the context described above [Ubuntu 18.04, MySQL 5.7]).

Comment: It is an optional. You are not forced to use it. If you think you are ok with that default initial things, just don't use.